# Assembly Resolve Not Fully Loading My DLL?

Tags: c#

I'm using a method to load a dll on an AssemblyResolve event.  It's not quite working the way I want it to.  Here's some code:

in my form load:

```
var a = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
a.AssemblyResolve += (object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) => LoadDLL(sender, args, anArg);
```

LoadDLL:

```
public Assembly LoadDLL(object sender, ResolveEventArgs agrs, bool anArg){
    //Let's just ignore anArg, it doesn't affect anything related to the problem
    asseblyPath = @"XXX";//path to my dll
    return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
}
```

So that's all well and good.  I set Copy Local to false for my DLL so the AssemblyResolve event is called and I can load the desired version of my DLL.

One strange thing that is happening is this: After running this code, my code tries to access a public variable from a class containing global constant values (this class should be in my DLL).

```
public class GCV{
    public GCV(){}
    public string value1= "asdf";
}
```

Unfortunately, when I'm in debug mode, GCV.value1 is set to null when it clearly has a value in the class definition.  This is one symptom that I can describe here, hopefully enough to diagnose the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: GCV.value1 is not a valid expression, value1 is not a static member of the class.

Comment: Removed the "assembly" tag; it is used for assembly-language questions.

Comment: Thanks for reclassifying my question, sometimes I can get a little tag happy heh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in debug the version loaded differ from the one it load in release. Try to look in the Output folder when debugging, and look for the Loaded .... to find your dll. This should point to a different version that the one you expect.

Comment: When I point to the dll in my project directory, it works like you said it would, but when I copy those exact dll files in the bin/debug and put them somewhere else and point to the new location where the copied files are, it continues to have the problem.  How can I remedy this? Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: well, a trick to discover the problem can be this: launch the program stand alone, and if it reproduce the problem, *attach* the debugger, even during attachment the list of loaded assembly is available in the output tab, so you cna discover wich version is loaded. I know it is not a solution,just a way to find it: in this case we can not guess where the problem is :)

Comment: The correct dll was loaded, the message reads: 'myApp.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded '*dllPath*', Symbols loaded.  So it looks like it was loaded, and the symbols loaded.  Does that help any?  Thanks! :)